# Need Removable comments in this textarea

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I need to add some content which would be clear on click in the given below textarea.

Not able to find the answer, please help me

```
  <tr><td><?php echo tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'soft', '60', '5'); ?></td></tr>
```

Comment: Where is your `tep_draw_textarea_field` function code ? or is it some type of framework ?

Comment: No framework, its Oscommerce application, need to add content in comments field,which will disappear on click in comments field,

Comment: Okay !! May this help's you ->http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/freeway/freeway_1_5_Alpha/admin/includes/functions/html_output.php

Comment: Yeah need the same one from your side, really thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to show a textarea box which displays some help text to encourage the user to complete it in a particular way?  And that as soon as the user clicks on the text area and starts to type?

Comment: What markup does the function generate?

Comment: nopes i have a box, need some permanent content in it and need to disappear them when the user will click on that content though he can write his/her own content. Could not able do it with in echo in php tag

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly, you want to display some text in your textarea, which will disappear when user moves focus to that textarea.

If you're using html5 it will be a simple task - just add a placeholder attribute to your textarea. I do not know what kind of php sript/framework are you using, but it should look like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="Click me to type something"></textarea>
```

If not, you should use javascript to achieve this result. There are lots of available solutions, for example:

[jQuery Placeholder](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/)

EDIT: I checked how the tep_draw_textarea_field function works, for html5 code you should use:

```
<?php echo tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'soft', '60', '5', '', 'placeholder="Click me"'); ?>
```